# How do I calculate the height and width difference?

Tags: math

Let's assume we have two geometric shapes like following

[image]

now we want to overlay Square for both shapes that has width 500 pixel and height 500 pixel so it look like following

[image]

The red square on the left side may appear larger than the red square on the right side even though they have the same dimensions ,the reason for that is that it fits with the mother's background

so i tried to make the dimensions of the red square look the same in both shapes , the solution
to this is to calculate the difference in the dimensions of the two backgrounds

**so for right shape**

divide height by width

```
500 * 3264/2448 = 666.6666666666666667 (which is the final width and height for red box)
```

**for left shape**

divide height by width

```
500 * 272/736 = 184.7826086956521739 (which is the final width and height for red box)
```

so the result is finally correct like this

[image]

Now finally my question is when i want to do the same previous arithmetic to an other shape
with width 1080 and height 1920 i noticed that i need to reverse the divide arithmetic
so must divide width by height instead of height by width to have the correct Dimension
difference like following

```
500 * 1080/1920 instead of 500 * 1920/1080
```

in the fact after many tests there are dimensions accept divide width by height and others
accept divide height by width in order to get the correct Dimension
difference for red box in previous explanation

How to know when should i divide height by width or divide width by height I didn't find a
clear rule to follow

Comment: A rule could also be "divide highest by lowest", so you always get a result ratio >= 1

Comment: thank you for response , yes some dimensions are proportional to the highest division of the lowest , while others are proportional to the lowest division of the highest , so I want a fixed rule for when I should reverse the division process or not to get correct results always  . I want to attach this rule to a specific program

Answer (score 0):

I have different idea.

I think this problem is to display object at the equal size under the difference resolution.
Am I right?

This problem is related to ration of real length to resolution.
In the upper example, if the length per 1pixel of left and right are equal, no problem occurred like this.

Why both of left and right must be changed?
I can only change left side.

I measured the length of top sides of these after downloading on the "paint".

```
W1=102mm, W2=70mm
w1=736pixel,w2=2448pixel
b1=W1/w1=0.138mm/pixel, b2=W2/w2=0.028mm/pixel
```

I don't know the unit of value 500, however I am sure it is pixel.

Calculate real length based on current resolution.

```
l1,l2 = 500pixel
L1=l1*b1=500pixel*0.138mm/pixel=69mm
L2=l2*b2=500pixel*0.028mm/pixel=14mm
```

As you can see, because the difference exists between b1 and b2, the displayed lengths are different.
So I changed the length of L1 depending on relation b1 and b2.

```
_l1=l1/b1*b2 = 500/0.138*0.028=101pixel
_L1=_l1*b1=101*0.138=14mm
```

Now when `_l1` is displayed instead of `l1`, the real length of left and right side are same in 14mm.

So, to resolve this problem, the ration of real length to pixel must be calculated. There is no relation to ratio width and height.

If my idea is bad, send message to me.
Thank you.

Comment: i think you are right with saying "  Why both of left and right must be changed? I can only change left side.  " but couldn't understand these values you provided in 'mm' could you please provide some graphics with a better explanation , you are near Ali to hit my need as well , How can i message you as you mentioned

Comment: It means millimeter. ali19901001ali@gmail.com

Comment: thanks a lot i don't know if it legal to share email here , but i have sent email to you